# How do I find the reason for a failed data node? (Elasticsearch 6.5)

Tags: elasticsearch, centos7

We have been running elasticsearch for a few years now. We ran a 2 node simple cluster (version 1.7). This cluster supported some internal utilities so it was relatively low use. In the last 4 years that cluster has never crashed, been restarted or even hiccuped.

We decided to set up a more production focused cluster. I did a lot of research and this is that I came up with for the new cluster:

```
2 Client Nodes (a.k.a. Coordinating nodes) [4 core, 8GB memory, 300GB HD, Virtual]
3 Master Nodes[4 core, 8GB memory, 300GB HD, Virtual] 
3 Data Nodes[48 core, 64GB memory, 3TB HD (Raid 0), Physical]
```

This cluster is running ES 6.5.4 CENTOS 7 (I am planning to upgrade to 7.1 soon).
All of nodes are operating on essentially vanilla configurations. We only have about 5 million documents and less than 60GB of data total for the cluster. The configuration looks something like this:

```
# Example Master Config
cluster.name: MYCLUSTER
node.name: MASTER01
node.master: true
node.data: false
node.ingest: false
cluster.remote.connect: false
path.repo: /repo/nfs/path

# Example Data Config
cluster.name: MYCLUSTER
node.name: DATA01
node.master: false
node.data: true
node.ingest: false
cluster.remote.connect: false
path.repo: /repo/nfs/path

# Example Client Config
cluster.name: MYCLUSTER
node.name: CLIENT01
node.master: false
node.data: false
node.ingest: false
cluster.remote.connect: false


# All have
http.port: MY_ES_PORT
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: MY_LIST_OF_SERVERS(8)
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
```

In jvm.options the heap space is at the default 1G for all nodes except the data nodes which are at 26G.

The problem is that my data nodes keep crashing. 3 times in the last 3 days one of my 3 data nodes has crashed. Bringing it back online and ridding myself of corrupted pieces of indexes has been many hours of work and learning. I can't figure out what is making them crash. I see errors in the log that refer to the "Failed Node" and "CorruptIndexException" but I have no idea what caused the actual node to fail. I have examined log files of all of the severs and while they all show errors none seem to have anything that helps me pinpoint the cause of the failure. 2 of the 3 data nodes have failed.

The interwebs seem to suggest that the most common reason for this is hardware. Unfortunately, I don't see any evidence that the hardware is the problem.

Can anyone offer any advice on how I can figure out why the data nodes are crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"CorruptIndexException" means that some segment is corrupted. maybe because of bad block (bad sector) on HDD. I recommend running checkdisk on HDD and then use elasticsearch-shard tools (located on $ELASTIC-HOME/bin/) to check and fix the corrupted segments.  perhaps the segment path is recorded on the log file.

quick guide for elasticsearch-shard:

```
./elasticsearch-shard remove-corrupted-data --index cl6-blah-blah-index  --shard-id 3
```

note that the elasticsearch-shard is available only on 6.5.

another important note: fsck and elasticsearch-shard may cause the data to lose.  although consider that the data is corrupted now and there is no way to recover it.

Comment: It does seem that hardware would be the most likely problem. Trying to run badblocks gives an error about not being able to find some shared libraries--running the same command on another physically identical server works. I'll see what I can find and report back. Thanks for the tip on the tool too--I thought it was only available in 7.1. I guess I misread that.

Comment: Adding to this... DATA03 can't run the badblocks command because of "missing" libraries, The library name listed is gibberish. DATA01 and DATA02 which are identical servers don't have this problem. Really staring to look like DATA03 has some corruption. Going to pull it out of the cluster and do some fscks. I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: the plot thickens... So after taking DATA03 out of the cluster everything migrates to the remaining to data servers except one index "crawledinventory_v1". I tried /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-shard remove-corrupted-data --index crawledinventory_v1 --shard-id 2 but got a big java exception in the initialization of the VM. Error: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag 48 in class file java/nio/CharBuffe

Comment: OK, After running `fsck` (or more specifically `shutdown -rF now` since I have one large partition) I'm 99.9% sure this is just a hardware issue. I haven't solved the problem yet but I have a suspicion that it may be something to do with the DELL perc controller and Raid 0. I have 2 other systems that are identical except they are Raid 5 and they seem to be 100% stable. If I can't `fsck` and `badblock` my way to a stable file system I may just rebuild them as raid 5. Our use case is mostly read intensive and low compared to what I've seen documented elsewhere. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's been days now and no more corrupt indexes. I switched my raid configuration from 0 to 5 and on the particular servers I have that seemed to do the trick. Anyone else reading this who runs into extremely frequent corrupt indexes should start troubleshooting by looking at the hardware--it is the most likely culprit.

Comment: 8 days since we fixed the hardware. System is stable and no corrupt indexes.